# lisp creating property list from strings

Tags: macros, plist, common-lisp, metaprogramming

Common LISP

Here's my problem: I would like to read columns headers from a csv file and create from those headers a function returning a plist where headers are properties names:

Let's say we have a csv file whose column headers are "Name", "Date", "Event".
From those 3 strings I'd like to create a function like:

```
(defun read-csv-line (x y z)
  (list :Name x :Date y :Event z))
```

so that reading further lines I'd write:

```
(read-csv-line "Bob" "1/1/1985" "Birthday")
```

I thought a macro would do the trick:

```
(defmacro convert-to-plist (x y z)
  `(defun read-csv-line (a b c)
     (list :,(intern x) a :,(intern y) b :,(intern z) c)))
```

But this syntax is not considered correct.

So how would you say I can do that? It'd be better of course with a variable number of arguments...

Thanks in advance!
yours,
h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
(defmacro convert-to-plist (x y z)
  `(defun read-csv-line (a b c)
     (list ,(intern x "KEYWORD") a 
           ,(intern y "KEYWORD") b
           ,(intern z "KEYWORD") c)))

(convert-to-plist "NAME" "DATE" "EVENT")    

(read-csv-line "Bob" "1/1/1985" "Birthday")
```

yields

```
(:NAME "Bob" :DATE "1/1/1985" :EVENT "Birthday")
```

Comment: This stays true to the original form that OP had (with a defun inside a defmacro), but that really doesn't seem very good form.

Comment: This works, but is rather far from a good solution (to start with, calling `(convert-to-plist "FOO" "BAR" "BAZ")` later on will overwrite the definition of `read-csv-line` and that's really far from ideal.

Comment: @Vatine I do not endorse this solution, I was only showing the OP where his mistake was.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this instead:

```
CL-USER 34 > (defun make-headers (strings &aux (package "KEYWORD"))
               (mapcar (lambda (name)
                         (intern (string-upcase name) package))
                       strings))
MAKE-HEADERS

CL-USER 35 > (defparameter *headers* (make-headers '("Name" "Date" "Event"))) 
*HEADERS*

CL-USER 36 > (defun read-csv-line (&key (headers *headers*) line)
               (pairlis headers line))
READ-CSV-LINE

CL-USER 37 > (read-csv-line :line (list "Bob" "1/1/1985" "Birthday"))
((:EVENT . "Birthday") (:DATE . "1/1/1985") (:NAME . "Bob"))
```